# Prove that $\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\text{dx}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}e}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

using inequalities of $L^p$ space how can we prove the following inequality:

> $$\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\text{dx}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}e}$$

Comment: Use cauchy schwarz with $u = e^{-x}$, $v = \frac{1}{\sqrt(1+x^2)}$

Comment: I don't think so , and that is what's written  @ablmf

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst thanks I thought that using Hölder's inequality would help

Comment: yes, it is holders inequality with $p = q = 2$, just a special case. It is so widely used that we give it its own name.